# Decompose nested maps into key-value pairs

Tags: clojure

I would like to decompose a nested map in Clojure into a sequence of key-value pairs. For example, let's have this map:

```
{:a :b
 :c {:d {:e :f
         :g :h}
     :i :j}}
```

This map decomposed should look like this:

```
[[:a :b]
 [:c {:d {:e :f
          :g :h}
      :i :j}]
 [:d {:e :f
      :g :h}]
 [:e :f]
 [:g :h]
 [:i :j]]
```

Order of the output does not matter.

I'm thinking about solving this with a recursive function, `tree-seq`, or `clojure.walk`. I suspect I might be missing something from the Clojure standard library. What would be the best solution to approach this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses `tree-seq`:

```
(defn decompose [m]
  (mapcat (partial tree-seq (comp map? val) val) m))
```

This produces a sequence of `MapEntry`s.

Comment: Thanks! I can add that this produces a sequence of vectors in ClojureScript.